# Subgit: avoid to synchronize git branches onto svn

Tags: git, svn, subgit

I am trying to use [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) but I am facing a problem with branches: I would like branches created under Git to live and die inside Git only. I found this: [SubGit: How to exclude branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588228/subgit-how-to-exclude-branches), but it says

> The troubles come from merge commits: if commit A is the result of merging branch foo into master, then SubGit creates branches/foo on Subversion side for corresponding parent of commit A. . If you'd prefer to not include SubGit generated branches into branches/* namespace, consider using some special branches on Subversion side as well

I don't want to mess with the SVN because I am evaluating Subgit and I don't want to change anything on SVN. I guess I could my goal (meaning, committing to SVN only the merged history and not also the git branch) by [rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) before pushing to the Git repository, but I am afraid this could lead to conflicts when committing back to SVN. Any idea on how I can workaround this, without waiting for SubGit version 2.1 (claimed to do what I want but not in a near future - cit from linked answer: `it's going to take some time before we implement it`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SubGit synchronizes only branches you've specified in the SubGit config file. By default they are:

```
    trunk = trunk:refs/heads/master
    branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
    shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

So if you use another namespace, e.g. refs/heads/nosync/*, branches in it won't be synchronized.

Or you can use refs/heads/* for normal branches (that are out of synchronization) and setup special refs/heads/sync/* namespace for synchronization:

```
    trunk = trunk:refs/heads/sync/master
    branches = branches/*:refs/heads/sync/*
    shelves = shelves/*:refs/shelves/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/tags/sync/*
```

Note, that long branch names (like refs/heads/sync/master) don't lead to inconvenience because after cloning such Git repository, you can assign your own local refs/heads/* branches with short names to track branches with long names from one or another namespace. That's why I think this is a good solution for you.

Comment: Actually, I tried yesterday this solution (which reflects the one I already found) and noticed that merge commits are not a problem, meaning they do not cause subgit to synchronize the `special branch namespace` onto svn. So, this is definitely the solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but in your example code block, shouldn't branches have `nosync` not `sync` in there?

Comment: The block is correct, `refs/heads/*` are not mentioned, so they are not synchronized; `refs/heads/sync/*` are mentioned, so they are synchronized.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I'd missed the point that in Git you'd be creating branches which are local to Git in `refs/heads//*` and since it's only bits that are mapped under '/refs/heads/sync` that are tracked relative to SVN, the Git-only branches won't be sync'd with SVN. Seems like a fairly neat solution - thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of creating the refs with short names when cloning the subgit repository?

Comment: I don't understand the question, please write to my e-mail (which can be found in my profile) what you mean by "short names". Probably you mean branches like 'master', but they are actually refs/heads/master in Git.